# Does MYSQL truncate a table when the tables size limit is reached?

Tags: php, mysql

I have been pouring over the MYSQL documentation trying to determine if my script or MYSQL itself is causing a truncation of a large table. The basic behavior I am seeing:

- A PHP script is kicked off from the browser to select rows from a MSSQL table and immediately insert them into a local MySQL database table.
- After determining the number of rows in MSSQL, my script breaks down the select into chunks to avoid any out of memory issues.
- The script then truncates the local table and starts to import the data by iterating over the chunks
- Following the data in MySQL directly, I see the table close in on ~200,000 rows and then suddenly the table truncates and the count starts over
- I would think that I would see some errors about the table being full and I didn't think MySQL would truncate the table if the table limit was reached.

Can anyone confirm whether or not MySQL would truncate a table automatically if the table limit is reached or a setting to check to turn off such behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No MySQL sets no hard limits on the size of the table, but there are some limits...

**Explicit table size**
You can set the max table size with

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name MAX_ROWS=200000
```

You can see the current settings for table size with

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM db_name LIKE 'tbl_name';
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/full-table.html

Note that `MAX_ROWS` is:

> The maximum number of rows you plan to store in the table. This is not a hard limit, but rather a hint to the storage engine that the table must be able to store at least this many rows.

**Filesystem limits**
MySQL 5.x has a default tablesize of 256TB, but if your filesystem does not allow files > 4GB, that might be a limit that can cause this behaviour as well.

**Memory limits**
If you're using the `memory` (heap) engine, your table size is determined by the `max_heap_table_size` system variable.

Comment: Thanks! I suspected it was not MySQL, but putting a nail in that coffin makes it easier to pinpoint the issue in my script.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think MySQL is truncating your data, I'v worked with tables with 500,000 rows or more and I had no problems at all. So, I think you better watch out your PHP Script or at least the PHP configuration, all the timeouts setting and size of the scripts that PHP can handle.

- max_execution_time
- max_input_time
- memory_limit

I hope this could help you.